# Lambda in lambda cannot be a template?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14, auto

The Visual Studio compiler (MSVC 2015) is unable to compile the following simple piece of code:

```
int main() {
    auto foo = [](auto callback) {
        callback(int{});
    };
    auto rexs = [&foo]() {
        foo([](auto tg) {});
    };
}
```

It barfs an internal compiler error:

```
fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
```

VC++ likes to give error `C1001` when the compiled code contains errors (i.e. the programmer made a mistake, but VC++ just doesn't fully recognize the mistake in the code), so I'm wondering if I could have made a mistake here.

However, from all perspectives I can see, my code looks standard-conformant, and it seems like a VC++ bug to me.  Am I thinking right?

Comment: "An internal error has occurred in the compiler." is always a bug (in the compiler / tool chain) whether the reproducing code is valid or not. Although, the bug is more severe when the code is valid.

Comment: `VC++ likes to give error C1001 when the compiled code contains errors (i.e. the programmer made a mistake, but VC++ just doesn't fully recognize the mistake in the code)`. Even if that is true, it's still a compiler error. If VS thinks the code is wrong, it should have a reason to think that.

Comment: @user2079303 I've seen C1001 so many times in my projects when I've made a small syntax mistake that I don't bother to scold my compiler for it anymore.

Comment: @Bernard You need a better compiler :)

Comment: @deviantfan I hope VS 2017 would be better :/ I don't have much choice for Windows, do I?

Comment: @Bernard Why not? GCC ("MinGW"), Clang, and ICC are all available on Windows too. VS 2017 (and I think, partially 2015 too) even (finally) managed to fully separate IDE from compiler, it's now possible to use VS as IDE with MinGW/Clang as compiler too (at least, MS and people are telling me that, I didn't try).

Comment: @deviantfan I didn't know that VS can be used with MinGW and Clang. I think it has to be set up manually though - the Clang that can be automatically installed is for iOS/OSX cross compilation. Not sure how nice the debugging experience will be like though. I'll have to try it out.

Comment: I upgraded to VS 2017 today and it fixes the issue (it also uncovered a few other areas where my code was not standard-compliant). Looks good so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code compiles fine with clang 3.8 and gcc 5.4 (http://rextester.com/SCAH69935) so it seems to be a VC++ bug.

Comment: "C1001" is *always* a VC++ bug.

Comment: It seems to compile fine on a VS 2017 online compiler. [This one.](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/)  Maybe it's time to upgrade.

Answer (score -2):

`VC++` is right: C++11 doesn't allow `auto` in lambda.
We can use `auto` in lambda only since C++14.

Clang 3.8.0 gives me this error with the `-std=c++11`:

```
main.cpp:7:17: error: 'auto' not allowed in lambda parameter
    auto f = [](auto x) { return x + 1;};
```

and gcc 7.1.0 (with the same flag) gives me this:
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

```
main.cpp:7:17: error: use of 'auto' in lambda parameter declaration only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14

     auto f = [](auto x) { return x + 1;};
```

for this code:

```
int main()
{
    auto f = [](auto x) { return x + 1;};
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make "internal compiler error" correct.

Comment: My tag was wrong.  It should be C++14.  Thank's for pointing it out.

Comment: true, but it doesn't means that the code is correct either

Comment: Even Microsoft says it supports generic lambdas in VS 2015: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: as Bernard pointed out, at the time I posted my answer, the tag of the question was C++11. C++11 doesn't allow auto in lambda. The compiler doesn't count as long as you compile for C++11 (and the compiler is fully C++11 compliant).